# Currently reading about cursor in postGreSql

Tags: database, postgresql

All the time that i deal with cursor, I always see that there is loop, iteration. So, is there any other way to use cursor rather that itaration?

Comment: Generally cursors are intended for looping through them, however cursors can also be used for being passed as parameters and finally be returned via FETCH ALL. See http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/plpgsql-cursors.html

Comment: @ZiggyCrueltyfreeZeitgeister that looks like an answer to me.

Comment: thanx a lot. will bear in mind